# How do I make R lattice xyplot ignore gaps in time and make a continuous timeseries plot?

Tags: r, xts, lattice

I have an xts series that I'm trying to plot. This series contains of intra-day date for a month with gaps in the data on the weekend. I use xyplot (lattice) in R to plot the time series and am very pleased with the results.

Unfortunately the plots keep the weekend gaps. I'd like to ignore the weekend gaps and make my timeseries plot continuous and would appreciate if someone pointed me in the right direction.

The current command is :

```
xyplot(close~MyTime, type='l', col='black',ylab='',xlab='', main='Test')
```

[image]

I tried JohnPaul's method and it 'nearly' works. The labels while present, don't render correctly. The last label only goes up to the 3rd of January, while the actual data extends all the way up to February. The command used was:

```
PlotOrd<-order(Mytime)
xyplot(close~PlotOrd, type='l', col='black',ylab='',xlab='', main='Close',scales=list( x=list( labels=MyTime))  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, what you wish to do is have the weekends not appear in the plot at all. One way to do this is to make another vector which is the order in which you want `close` plotted - a vector that does not include weekends.  Assuming that weekends are not included in `time` this should work:

```
PlotOrd<-order(Mytime)

xyplot(close~PlotOrd, type='l', col='black',ylab='',xlab='', main='Test')
```

This will give you the correct plot, but your x axis tick labels will just be the number from `PlotOrd`. If you want to keep them as dates add a `scales` argument for the x axis, like so:

```
xyplot(close~PlotOrd, type='l', col='black',ylab='',xlab='', main='Test',
scales=list( x=list( labels=Mytime )) )
```

**EDIT**

One way to control the axis labels is to use the `at` argument as well. It is kind of clunky here and I wish I could come up with a more elegant idea, but this will work:

```
xyplot(close~PlotOrd, type='l', col='black',ylab='',xlab='', main='Test',
scales=list( x=list(at=c(50,100,150,200), labels=Mytime[c(50,100,150,200)] )) )
```

This will put ticks at observations 50,100,150 and 200, and will give corresponding values from `MyTime` as the label. The downside is you have to write in the ticks yourself. You could add some code  to make a sequence of values. Say you want a label every 15 days. If you figure out how many measurements that corresponds to, you can  make a sequence of numbers that far apart (call it `MyTicks`). Then  feed to `at=MyTicks` and `labels=MyTime[MyTicks]`. Still it would be nicer to have lattice just pick the ticks for you...

Comment: Hi John Paul thank you for the response. What is PlotOrdxyp ? I assume its the same as PlotOrd. Indeed when I change the index to integers I can get them in one continuous plot, however I lose the dates. When I try the second method suggested by you, I get an error : Error in ans$labels[ok] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @user1480926 - It should be PlotOrd - sorry about the typo I fixed it above. My guess on the second error is that `time` is the name of a function in R and so it is confused and is can't fine your data called  "time". Try renaming or putting your "time" into a new vector that has a unique name and that should work. I edited the answer above using `MyTime` as the new vector.

Comment: hi yes this works thank you very much !!! Thank you for explaining this so clearly

Comment: Hi John Paul the times dont quite work. See the attached image above to see what happens when I do what you suggested

Comment: Note that the time horizon of the data is five minutely, and the graph extends to the entire month. The original rendering of time takes this into account and seems to plot the dates correctly, but the scale command doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Oops - the scales command is putting the first value of `MyTime` on the first x axis tic, and the second value on the second tic etc. Need to fix that.

Comment: right so how do I know the number of visible tics so that I can adjust for it ?

Comment: @user1480926 I am trying to think of a better way, but a simple one is to use the `at` argument in scales. You give at a bunch of numbers e.g. at=c(10,20,30) it will put the ticks there. This would be the 10th, 20th, 30th value, Then tell the labels to put the correct labels by giving the same values to labels - I will edit above.

Comment: I think this is probably the closest I'm going to get to get full control. Thank you once more John Paul